# Collapse values from multiple rows of a column into an array when all other columns values are same

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a table with 7 columns where for every few rows, 6 columns remain same and only the 7th changes. I would like to merge all these rows into one row, and combine the value of the 7th column into a list.

So if I have this dataframe:

```
   A  B  C
0  a  1  2
1  b  3  4
2  c  5  6
3  c  7  6
```

I would like to convert it to this:

```
   A       B  C
0  a       1  2
1  b       3  4
2  c  [5, 7]  6
```

Since the values of column A and C were same in row 2 and 3, they would get collapsed into a single row and the values of B will be combined into a list.

Melt, explode, and pivot don't seem to have such functionality. How can achieve this using Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with custom lambda function, last add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for same order of columns by original:

```
f = lambda x: x.tolist() if len(x) > 1 else x
df = df.groupby(['A','C'])['B'].agg(f).reset_index().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
```

You can also create columns names dynamic like:

```
changes = ['B']
cols = df.columns.difference(changes).tolist()

f = lambda x: x.tolist() if len(x) > 1 else x
df = df.groupby(cols)[changes].agg(f).reset_index().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df)
   A       B  C
0  a       1  2
1  b       3  4
2  c  [5, 7]  6
```

For all lists in column solution is simplier:

```
changes = ['B']
cols = df.columns.difference(changes).tolist()

df = df.groupby(cols)[changes].agg(list).reset_index().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df)
   A       B  C
0  a     [1]  2
1  b     [3]  4
2  c  [5, 7]  6
```

Comment: Thank you. That was really helpful. I realised immediately after posting that I should have been looking at groupby and not at pivot. May I ask what is the purpose of ```reindex(df.columns, axis=1)``` since the result seems to be the same without it as well.

Comment: @gouravkr - I add it because wihtout columns are `A,C, B` instead `A,B,C`, so it change order like original columns names

Comment: OK. Also, what is the ```[changes]``` doing, as, again, the result seems to be same without that.

Comment: @gouravkr - It is solution for defined only column with changes, so you can grouping by all columns without `changes` column(s). But you can also use `df.groupby(['A','C'])['B'].agg(f)`, but if 7 columns typing it is a lot, so I simoplify soluion. I hope it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach using [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) and [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
(df.pivot_table(index='A',aggfunc=list).applymap(lambda x: x[0] if len(set(x))==1 else x)
                                                                 .reset_index())
```

---

```
   A       B  C
0  a       1  2
1  b       3  4
2  c  [5, 7]  6
```